# Syncing between computers using RSS Owl doesn't retain labeled entries

Tags: rss, rss-reader

I am using RSS Owl to follow tags on Stack Overflow. For each entry in the RSS feed, I have assigned defined labels to state the action that I took for that entry.

**Problem**

Although RSS Owl allows you to export your feeds, labels, and preferences so you can input them into RSS Owl on another computer, it does not seem to retain the tag assignments for the RSS entries. When I exported from one instance of RSS Owl, I specified that I want to export the labels and the preferences. The feeds shows up in the export and the label definitions. However, none of the entries show their assigned labels.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Is there another RSS reader that is better for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might belong in a bug report instead of a Stack Overflow question. Please post it on their issue tracker:

https://github.com/rssowl/RSSOwl/issues